# JPA updation not reflect on db

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

we use entities are

```
public class User  implements Cloneable,Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected long id;

    @NotNull
    protected String userName;

    @NotNull
    protected String email;

    @NotNull
    protected String firstName;

    @NotNull
    protected String lastName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    protected List<UserCompanyRoles> userRoles; 
}
public class UserCompanyRoles implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserCompanyRoles.class);
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserID")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RoleID")
    private Role role;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CompanyID")
    private Company company;
}
```

this entity  user update by using dao

```
protected boolean update(Object entity,Long id) {
        EntityManager entityManager = null;
        EntityTransaction tx = null;
        try {
            entityManager = this.createEM();
            tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            Object objToUpdate = retrieve(entity.getClass(), id);
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(objToUpdate, entity);
            entityManager.merge(objToUpdate);
            entityManager.flush();
            tx.commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            return false;
        } finally {
            if(tx!=null){
                tx.rollback();
            }
            if (entityManager != null && entityManager.isOpen()) {
                this.closeEM(entityManager);
            }
        }
    }
```

this code works for some time but. some time that newly added usercompanyrole not inserted into table.
they could not throw error on time of updation.
that will only some time other wise it will work good.
we have no idea to solve this problem.
that will be work good after restarting my server.

Comment: Without any code hard to tell. But, what does smell bad is when you say each user has an entity manager stored as a static variable. If you declare a field as `static` then you can only have one per app, not per user.

Comment: Your code implies you are using JTA and the container is injecting the EntityManager into your thread - I have no idea why someone would make this variable static, but it seems like it would be the source of problems.  It should not be static, as each thread needs its own EntityManager instance.  Chances are it is the source of this problem, as EntityManagers are not thread safe, and the stack trace you've shown is due to locking - one thread is waiting because some other thread has a lock on something.

Comment: @Chris we are using another entity manger factory for another persistence unit or entity. when create a new entity manger by using that another entity Manger Factory then new updated entities not reflected on db. that problem only for the List<UserCompanyRoles> userRoles;  in user class

Comment: You have edited the question into something completely different as nothing of the original problem remains. It would have been better if you posted what was wrong, and then opened a new question - but you haven't really put in enough information to help solve the current problem as the code given is generic so we have no idea how you are creating and merging anything.